# Not able to understand role of param tag

Tags: c#

I am new to development and wanted to ask a very basic question, I was looking some code in C# and trying to reproduce the application I am not getting what to do when I come across param tag with three slash, check out the below example :-

```
/// <param name="requestMethod">one of GET, PUT, DELETE</param>
```

Two & three slashes are used for comments, so is this a comment or I need to remove comment and put the value as described.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: this looks like a comment on how a method in a mvc-controller is accessed... - however, without some more surrounding code it is hard to tell what it exactly is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three slashes `///` are XML comments whereas two slashes `//` are just standard comments found in the code.

So as you can see the XML comment with the three slashes has information about the method as a whole, whereas the `//` comment in the main body of the method is just a comment about a part of that method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Does something.
/// </summary>
///<param name="param1">The parameter .</param>
public void doSomething(int param1)
{
     // This is a standard comment about some code

}
```

So when calling this method you would do:

doSomething(999)

The Line     `///<param name="param1">The parameter .</param>` Means that this method expects you to pass in something as a parameter

For more info about using XML methods see here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302121.aspx

Comment: thanks for your comment... but I want to know that if there is a param tag after /// as i have mentioned earlier do i need to remove the comment or i might expect some param values to be added later in the script...

Comment: @MohdWasiHirekudi I have added some more info to my answer, but basically if you see the Param line it means when you call that method it expects you to pass in a parameter.  Also the XML comment has no relation to how the method works, so removing the comment wont change the need to pass in a parameter

Answer (score 1):

It's for [documenting code](http://rlieving.blogspot.com/2007/09/documenting-code-in-visual-studionet.html).

From above link:

> the 'param' tags define each parameter

In your example, the document is describing the values that can be passed into `requestMethod`.  Without seeing the method signature, it's hard to determine if these values are the strings `GET`, `PUT`, and `DELETE` or possibly C# enum values.

See also article from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288481%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a special kind of comment.

In Visual Studio if you press /// above a method it will automatically create the information for you, based on the current method.

This is used for documentation and and you can get the compiler to generate an xml file with this information with the /doc  commandline option.

See Microsofts recommendations:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx